# I am struggling to access data in a .json file

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I go about accessing the ID data from a .json file? I have attached an image that shows all product ids and I need to get them all.

[image]

```
jQuery.getJSON('/products.json', function(product) {
console.log(product);
});
```

**UPDATE:**

The following code gets the individual products array, how would I randomly choose one? I want to be able to get just 1 and then get the data from that random selection.

```
$.getJSON('/products.json', function(product) {

           $.each(product.products, function(i, data){ 
             console.log(data);

           });
   });
```

[image]

Comment: It's not enough to post a screen shot ..Please, post your code and what you've tried so far

Comment: I'm unable to view the image on the link posted. Maybe you could add a snippet of your file here?

Comment: Yeah, my bad I have made the changes now, the code is all I have so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
product.products[x].id
```

product <-- your object

products <-- array within the object

product[x] <-- xth item in the array

id <-- field within the array object

Answer (score 2):

To get a specific ID, in your shown example, call products[x].id, where x can be any number from 0 to 4.

If you want to loop through all products and do something with each id, then you can do:

```
products.forEach(product => {
    console.log(product.id);
    \\ do something else with product.id
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to use JavaScript and utilize the [forEach method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
const jsonFile = require('./products.json');
const data = JSON.parse(jsonFile);

data.forEach(element => console.log(element.id));
```